# Does this OpenCV code run on the GPU or the CPU?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to do image processing on the GPU for a class requirement.
Does this OpenCV code run on the GPU or CPU?

```
// The "Square Detector" program.
// It loads several images sequentially and tries to find squares in
// each image
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    int thresh = 50, N = 11;
    const char* wndname = "Square Detection Demo";
    static void findSquares( const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
    {
        squares.clear();
        
        Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
        pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
        pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        
        // find squares in every color plane of the image
        for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
        {
            int ch[] = {c, 0};
            mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
            for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
            {
                if( l == 0 )
                {
                    Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                    dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
                }
                else
                {
                    gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;
                }
                
                findContours(gray, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
                
                vector<Point> approx;
               for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
                {
                    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);
                    if( approx.size() == 4 &&
                       fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                       isContourConvex(Mat(approx)) )
                    {
                        double maxCosine = 0;
                        
                        for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                        {
                            // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                            double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                            maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                        }
                        
                        // if cosines of all angles are small
                        // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                        // vertices to resultant sequence
                        if( maxCosine < 0.3 )
                            squares.push_back(approx);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: only special functions run on gpu (ocl:: cuda:: gpu::) and some/many general functions if you use special hardware or libraries (e.g  tegra e.g. IPP)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Micka said, in OpenCV 2.4 GPU optimizations are explicit. You need to use API from `cv::gpu::` (CUDA implementation) or from `cv::ocl::` (OpenCL implementation) instead of plain API from `cv::`.

In OpenCV 3.0 new transparent API optimization were added (implemented on OpenCL). To enable them, you need to use `cv::UMat` contained instead of `cv::Mat` and use the same API from `cv::` namespace. The library will automatically use GPU optimizations if available.